# Why does Task Manager show all per-process network activity as 0 Mbps?

Tags: windows-10, networking, task-manager

I'm running Windows 10 Pro x64 version 2004, and while trying to get a handle on network performance of a process (the home network impact disaster that is the Epic Store client, but that's another story) I found that although network activity shows up properly in Task Manager's Performance tab in the section for my Ethernet adapter, the per-process network statistics in the Processes tab shows nothing, i.e. 0 Mbps, for every process, although clearly in the software and according to the Performance tab there is network activity. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use Windows 10's bridged networking with the OpenVPN-provided Windows TAP driver. This creates a separate "Network Bridge" adapter in the "Network Connections" adapters window, and the separate adapters that are bridged lose all of their own protocol/service/client entries in favour of those for the "Network Bridge" adapter.

[A reply to an old Windows community forum post about a similar issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-task-manager-not-showing-network-usage/5361cdf8-9ee5-4c9c-8728-6c0eda9956d6) suggested removing network filter drivers associated with the network adapter, such as VirtualBox's, and as I have VirtualBox installed, I removed its "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" service from the "Network Bridge" adapter, but that had no effect.

However it prompted me to try removing my wired Ethernet adapter from the bridge entirely, and after doing so and restarting my network activity, per-process network statistics in the Processes tab started showing up right away.